# Does an iPhone Enterprise provisioning profile need to specify phone UUIDs like an ad-hoc provisioning profile does?

Tags: iphone, distribution, enterprise, provisioning

We are an iPhone Developer Program member. We've got a DUNS number but not the 500 employees necessary to join the iPhone Developer Enterprise Program. Therefore I can can't see how things exactly operate for the Enterprise level. But we have customers that are big enough to be Enterprise developers and we could distribute our applications to them, and let them build and distribute them on their own. Ideally they could build our app, and distribute it and the associated enterprise distribution provisioning profile via their web site, and users could install both via iTunes.

But... do they need to put every potential user's iPhone UUID in the enterprise distribution provisioning profile as we have to do as individual developers when we do ad-hoc distribution? I am thinking that they don't (have to include all UUIDs) but can't really find anything that specifically says this. Does anyone have experience with this and could shed some light on it, even better with pointers to where this is detailed or explained?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using an iOS Enterprise Program distribution deployment method does NOT require you to enter every device id.

All you need is a distribution certificate for signing and a provisioning profile built for it.  Note that ANYONE that has the profile can run the app on their device, although you can revoke the profile if necessary.

You are also given the standard test and Ad Hoc deployment mechanisms as with the standard Development Program.  The Ad Hoc is limited to 100 devices, which I don't understand, but anyway, there it is.

Answer (score 3):

In September 2010, the program was modified by Apple to allow any organization with a DUNS number to apply. Prior to this date, only organizations of 500 or more employees were allowed to join the program. This change should provide much wider access to development of "enterprise apps". See http://www.apperian.com/technotes/Apple_iOS_Enterprise_Developer_Program.html for more information.

Comment: And any organisation can apply for a DUNS number for free (although I don't have the link to hand).