# Why does the developer apple site not create an ad hoc distribution provisioning profile?

Tags: iphone, uuid, ios-provisioning, ad-hoc-distribution, provisioning-profile

I am attempting to create an Ad Hoc Distribution Provision Profile from Apple's iOS Provisioning Portal with no success. I've selected Distribution Method: Ad Hoc, entered a Profile name, my Distribution Certificate doesn't expire until 6/28/2012, selected an APP ID and DID NOT select any Devices(Optional) click submit and I get no profile.

If I perform the same steps but select a Device I works.

I ran the process about a month ago to test the deployment of an app and it worked fine

Why does the process not provide a profile if I do not select a device? Has Apple made a change to the process that I might not be aware of?

Thanks

Comment: why do you require ad hoc distribution which does not have any device added??

Comment: my understanding is that I should then be able to distribute the app to any user.  am I mistaken?

Comment: you can not send ad hoc build to any user without adding his/her device into profile

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there Apple changed anything, but why would you want an ad Hoc Profile without a device? There is no way to use the resulting build on any device then, or am I mistaking?

Comment: This application is an inhouse application that will be used on over 300 phones.  I am using the Enterprise membership.

Comment: Aha. Got no experience in the enterprise membership. 

This any help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3251291/does-an-iphone-enterprise-provisioning-profile-need-to-specify-phone-uuids-like-a

Answer (score 0):

If you are a member of an Enterprise developer team, you can only create the distribution certificate if you are the team agent.