# IPA file + plist required for Overthe air installation?

Tags: javascript, ios, html, ios5

i am facing a problem, i have an ipa file with me i need to prepare this for overthe air installation procedure which can be shared. i have an windows environment.
I need to upload a .ipa file alone. but what i understood from various blogs i need to create the .plist file which has bundle identifier,version and Application URl.
As per my investigation i found that these information is available with in .ipa file this is stored in the Info.plist file with in .ipa.
i want to know how can i read these information from the .ipa file in the javascript environment and prepare the plist file required for overthe air installation.

Please can anybody help me solving this?

Answer (score 0):

When you publish your app for Enterprise distribution, the .plist file you are concerned about will be produced for you (along with the .ipa). If you actually want to distribute with an Ad Hoc certificate, just use the Ad Hoc certificate when signing the app for Enterprise distribution.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8439127/ios-enterprise-distribution-through-ota) for more information

Comment: hi, the problem here i have is don't have any XCODE dev iDe nor i use MAC platform. How can i get this while using a pure windows environment? The problem is when some one sends me an ipa file and i want to prepare this for oTA w/o mac environment?

Comment: The person who send you just an .ipa file should read the instructions I reference, then send you both the .ipa and .plist file that they created. It gets created for you already. Tell that person to send it your way.

Answer (score 0):

So are you receiving the ipa file? Then you need to make sure your device is linked to the account that it is dustributed under.
You can then import the ipa file into iTunes (mac or windows) sync your device and it wil be on there.

All the set up is done through the provisional portal in a web browser. Once you have the ipa file and you have it signed with the right certificate (which you need anyway) you are good to go. The info.plist or any other plist is no longer necessary - that is part of the app and can be read by any ios device.

The certificate is going to be your main issue if you want to install it on more devices than you planned on before you build the ipa file.

Comment: Thanks for the insights.But my scenario is different. i recive just an ipa file and on click of it from the device i should be able to install w/o even opening the itunes. i assume this is possible only via the plist. itms: link. for this i need to generate the plist and encapsulate with itms link right???    Example scenario is : Enduser who is using windows desktop uploads ipa file and when opened from device it should automatically install!

Comment: as per my research i though i would follow the below approach please comment if i am wrong. 1. unzip the .ipa file 2. look for info.plist file within it. 3. look for values within it 4. generate the Over the Air plist file. 5. Give server url which stores Ipa file within plist file. 6. encapsulate itms link and give the plist url. By this procedure i can arrive at the solution what i want.  is this approach correct??? In the above approach i don't no need to unzip an ipa file in the javascript environment find plist file and read the values.Steps 1 2 and 3 are not clear to me can any one help?

Comment: Ok I have never tried it that way before, but that is 6 steps that seem rather complicated instead of the itunes way. Good Luck:-)