# Cannot find option to create iOS inhouse distribution certificate

Tags: ios, code-signing-certificate, ios-provisioning, in-house-distribution

I've been trying to generate in-house app distribution certificate and profile but without much success.
I have followed instructions in **App Distribution Guide** and **Distributing Enterprise Apps for iOS Devices**, but I've been going in circles for two days.

Here are synopsis:

1. I am a member of **iOS Developer Enterprise Program** team.
2. I have **Admin** access.
3. I have generated **CSR**.
4. When I try to add iOS certificate via portal I only have two options that are available **iOS App Development** (under development grouping) and **App Store and Ad Hoc** (under distribution grouping). All other options are disabled and there is no option for in-house distribution certificate at all (screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkCLD.png).

[image: screen shot]

I must be missing something, but I am not sure what exactly. Any help is appreciated.
One more piece of information that might or might not matter is that I am a member of multiple teams (enterprise and standard dev).

Thanks!

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8439318/352891) explains the process

Comment: The post above explains the final step. The problem that I'm having is prior to that step, the "Simply create provisioning profile". Apple provisioning portal had an overhaul last night and one of the things that seems to be missing in the new portal is the ability to "Simply create provisioning profile" for inhouse apps as there doesn't seem to be a way to generate distribution certificate for inhouse apps which you need in order to sign the distribution provisioning profile.

Comment: I created a thread on apple dev forums and it seems like I'm not the only one having this issue. Here is a link to the thread for future reference: https://devforums.apple.com/thread/183805?tstart=0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is no longer an issue. There was a bug when Apple rolled out the new provisioning portal.
When you tried to create distribution profile the portal didn't detect distribution certificates you had, so you were unable to create one. This bug was fixed within 48h by Apple. Here is a link to the discussion on Apple developer forums for future reference: https://devforums.apple.com/thread/183805?tstart=0

Answer (score 1):

Here is a screenshot of what you should be seeing. Also, you mentioned you are a part of multiple development teams. When you log in to your developer account, it should ask you to select a team (don't have a screenshot for that). Select your Enterprise team. Log out of your developer account and log back in. Hopefully you should see this selection.

[image]

Comment: Neither of these two is the answer, but this is no longer an issue. I posted a link to apple dev forums discussion in the comments below my original question. I posted this question on the day Apple rolled out the new provisioning portal. The portal was buggy and when you tried to create distribution profile the portal didn't detect distribution certificates you had, so you were unable to create one. This bug was fixed within 48h by Apple.

Answer (score 1):

You are signed into a standard account. That screen is not an Enterprise account screen. When you signed in to the site did you choose the correct team?  You may be signed into your own account team instead of the enterprise team.