# Which is the most preferred way for distributing an enterprise iOS application with-in the organization?

Tags: ios, ios-enterprise

Which is the most preferred way for distributing an enterprise iOS application with-in the organization? Since this is an enterprise application, user has to be authenticated before they download? Which is the commonly practiced approach for this? (If this question doesn't belong to this area, please suggest the correct one)

Comment: I have app ready with enterprise licence. How do I host it in a server, such that users can download it. And what is the preferred method used by enterprise applications to make sure it is downloaded by only iOS devices which belong to company's user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. AFAIK [Testflight](https://www.testflightapp.com/) is the most preferred way for distrubuting an enterprise iOS applications with in the organization.
2. Yes user has to be authenticated before they download your enterprise app and it is optional.Since it is generated using enterprise distribution, any one can install the app in devices. So i would suggest to protect your app with some authentication mechanism.
3. It depends on your need. We were using a simple protected webserver for OTA and for some clients IBM worklight (it is a cross mobile paltform tool which gives a way to distribute the app) . Testflight is also providing [security](http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/835394-what-about-enterprise-apps-) for your Apps. Find the below statement from Test flight

> If you are a registered developer with an enterprise account and are
>   making apps for in-house distribution, TestFlight works with those
>   too. TestFlight fully supports enterprise apps and it works much like
>   ad hoc apps for distribution. Just upload an application signed with
>   an enterprise provisioning profile and distribute to your team and
>   only approved members of your team will have access to the application
>   for installation.

---

For Production release you can go for any one of the following way

1. [Volume Purchase Program](http://images.apple.com/business/docs/VPP_Business_Guide_USA_EN_Feb14.pdf)
2. [MDM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_device_management) It comes with some $$. I have personally used [MobileIron](http://www.mobileiron.com/en/iOS7-security-management-mdm-business)
3. Simply host a webserver a distribute the app via OTA.
   NOTE :
   You can find the details in this [link](http://images.apple.com/iphone/business/docs/iOS_Enteprise_Deployment_Overview_EN_Feb14.pdf) under the headings `Enterprise in house apps`.
   Here is the example for [Wireless Distribution of enterprise apps](http://blog.appliedis.com/2012/10/29/wireless-distribution-of-enterprise-ios-apps/).Regarding the security part you have to make sure that your webserver link is protected with user name and password such as linking with LDAP or custom code to validate.

Comment: Thanks for answering.. Iam not distributing for testing purpose.. It is for the users. As per my understanding testflight is for beta testing.

Comment: Sorry i thought it is for testing. You can go for [Volume Purchase program](http://images.apple.com/business/docs/VPP_Business_Guide_USA_EN_Feb14.pdf) or You need to have a [MDM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_device_management) Solutions. Personally i have used [MobileIron](http://www.mobileiron.com/en/iOS7-security-management-mdm-business) If you want to distribute only to small number of users you can build a webserver to distribute apps

Comment: See SO question [IOS Enterprise Distribution Through OTA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8439127/ios-enterprise-distribution-through-ota)

Answer (score 2):

I think the most common way would be the developper enterprise program if it is within your own company. More information can be found here:
https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/

If the distribution is to other companies.You should go for the Custom B2B Apps Program. More information can be found here:
http://www.apple.com/business/vpp/

The other options are not really an option because they are mostly intended for releasing publicly or releas for testing purposes.

Comment: Not sure if you have addressed OP's question.

Comment: I have app ready with enterprise license. How do I host it in a server, such that users can download it. And what is the preferred method used by enterprise applications to make sure it is downloaded by only iOS devices which belong to company's user?