# How can I privately host an Iphone application on the appstore?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

I've recently developed an application for the place that I work, and they many colleagues would like to use it.

These colleagues live miles away, and my research has told me it's very hard/impossible to load iPhone apps onto a non-jailbroken device.

So I would like to know if it is possible to put an app on the appstore for free, but only allow people with login credentials to access it or something?

Comment: Its look like you want to share pre release build so why don't you use test flight for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably it is not so hard as you thought. You can use over the air distribution, without upload app to AppStore. You can find lots of useful info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8439127/ios-enterprise-distribution-through-ota).

Answer (score 0):

1. Register an [Apple ID](https://appleid.apple.com/account) (Or you already have one)
2. Join the [Apple Developer Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/) (Cost you $99 every year)
3. Archive your app using AdHoc certificate, every device registered in the provisioning profile will be able to install the app

Answer (score 0):

You can use [iTunes Connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/) and keep your app in preview version or beta version. You can also add 1000 external users for your app and 25 internal users.
Internal users will get update just after you upload new build of your app and external will get after beta review. You just need users name and email [This](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/iTunesConnect_Guide.pdf) would be helpful for you.