# What are the ways to host iOS builds (ipa) except AppStore or any 3rd party tools?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, ipa

We are developing a iOS app using react-native. We want to host the build file  of app (.ipa) from a server without using AppStore or any 3rd party tool.

How can we do it? Is there any way to host the app like a web application hosting from cloud.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IOS Enterprise Distribution Through OTA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8439127/ios-enterprise-distribution-through-ota)

Answer (score 0):

Use "Hockey App" , which is a microsoft certified and behave like App Store realise.

Follow the below link:

```
https://hockeyapp.net/
```