# Is it necessary to pair devices in order to write PhoneGap applications?

Tags: cordova

I'm an html developer, so I'm used to pressing "Save" in Dreamweaver and my users being able to download my changes immediately.
So I'm so excited about the potential for PhoneGap.

We have signed up to the Apple Enterprise program because that allows us to publish iPad applications on our website:

https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/gettingstarted/ says:

"With your iOS Developer Enterprise Program ... your users can install your app ... wirelessly through a secure web server. "

In Dreamweaver CS6, the PhoneGap build service has built my "Hello World" application, except the iOS option says that a signing key is required.

The phonegap site says to 
Ensure that this provisioning profile is correctly paired with the device(s) you wish to test on.

https://build.phonegap.com/docs/ios-builds

But I don't want to pair to a particular device(s).
I want to publish my Hello World app to my website and have users download my changes immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  This is referring to ad-hoc distribution, where you can distribute test builds to up to 100 devices without going through the app store.

If you are a member of the Enterprise program you can still do this, but you should also have the option to create an [Enterprise provisioning profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3251291/does-an-iphone-enterprise-provisioning-profile-need-to-specify-phone-uuids-like).